# How does this SQL query fetch records?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a sql query which i am firing on a MDB Database.

`select * from Products where itemname & ' ' & size & ' ' & quality='A/G RATIO  Patient Price' Order by Category`

It is bringing me the record where `itemname` is `A/G RATIO` (There is only one record where itemname is `A/G RATIO`).

My Product table has `ItemName`, `size` and `quality` columns but in a particular row, value `'A/G RATIO'` is in Itemname and `'Patient Price'` in quality columns but how come these values are checked in a single condition `'A/G RATIO  Patient Price'`.

I think there is something about `&` operator which i could't find of [Google](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=31&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=ampersand+operator+in+sql+query&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=ampersand+operator+in+sql+query&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bc7998ee1acacccf&biw=1360&bih=667) and i am missing. What is that? What is the meaning of this sql query?

Comment: When working with strings, the & operator in MS Access is similar to the + operator in other DBMS's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query compares `'A/G RATIO Patient Price'` with the concatenation of the value on `itemname` column, space, the value on `size` column, space, and the value on `quality` column.